# How to read Android crash log?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, crash-dumps

I have published my first Android app on the Google Play store a few days ago. Now a crash log is available in the Developer Console and I am trying to find out what caused the crash. Although I un-obfuscated the stack trace I have difficulties to understand the crash log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MyApp/com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity.void setEntryStart(java.util.Date)(Unknown Source)
                                                                    void setCategory(com.example.MyApp.Common.Model.BookingDetail)
                                                                    void loadViewModel(android.os.Bundle)
                                                                    void putAddresDetailUUID(java.lang.String,com.example.MyApp.Common.Model.AddressDetail,android.os.Bundle)
                                                                    void putDate(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,android.os.Bundle)
                                                                    void doSave(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity$OnEditorTaskCompleteListener)
                                                                    void saveRecurringTemplate(boolean,boolean,boolean,com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity$OnEditorTaskCompleteListener)
                                                                    void closeEditor(boolean,boolean,boolean)
                                                                    void access$0(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity)
                                                                    void access$5(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,java.lang.String)
                                                                    void access$6(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,android.view.View)
                                                                    void access$7(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,java.util.Date)
                                                                    void access$11(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,com.example.MyApp.Common.Model.Enums.Priorities)
                                                                    void access$13(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,com.example.MyApp.Common.Model.AddressDetail)
                                                                    void access$25(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,double)
                                                                    void access$27(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,boolean)
                                                                    void access$28(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,boolean,boolean,boolean)
                                                                    void access$36(com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity,boolean,boolean,boolean,com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity$OnEditorTaskCompleteListener)
at com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity.void onCreate(android.os.Bundle)(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
... 11 more
```

Obviously the crash was caused by a `NullPointerException` but how to find the exact source? Do I have to read the stack trace top-down or bottom-up? So far I think the trace has two parts:

- 'dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)' is the first element in the stack.
- Staring from here all the other methodes in the stack, up to `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity` have been called.
- **Right?**
- While the app was executing `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity` an `NullPointerException` occurred. The exact location of the exception is specified in the second part of the log starting at the bottom line.
- The first methode of my own code is `com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity.void onCreate` that called
- **Right?**

The next lines I do not understand: The methodes that are listed here, like `void setEntryStart` or `void setCategory` are of cause part of `AddressEditorActivity` but NOT called directly from `onCreate`.

Is this just a list of methodes of `AddressEditorActivity` that have been used at **any** time during the lifetime of the activity or does this mean, that these methodes called each other? But `setEntryStart` does not call `setCategory` or vice versa...

Do have to read this method list top-down or bottom up? Starting with `setEntryStart` it makes sense to follow the list down to `closeEditor` (start activity, setup properties and view model, edit data, save data, close editor) but what do the `access$XY` entries mean? They do not make any sense for me.

Do I have to look for a possible cause of the `NullPointerException` in `setEntryStart` or in `access$36(...)` (what would that be) or at a completly different location?

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT:**
@shayan pourvatan, @Pankaj

This is the code of `setEntryStart`

```
private Date _entryStart;
private void setEntryStart(Date start) {
    _entryStart = start;
    if (_entryEnd != null && _entryStart != null && _entryEnd.before(_entryStart))
        _entryEnd = _entryStart;
}

private Date _entryEnd;
private void setEntryEnd(Date end) {
    _entryEnd = end;
    if (_entryEnd != null && _entryStart != null && _entryEnd.before(_entryStart))
        _recurringStart = _entryEnd;
}
```

The only possibility for a `NullPointerException` would be `_entryEnd.before(_entryStart)` with `_entryEnd` being null, wouldn't it? But if `_entryEnd != null` is checked before and as far as I know the further evaluation of the if-statment is canceld if a condition fails. Thus `_entryEnd.before(_entryStart)` is not called if `_entryEnd` is null, is it?

Comment: i think you have problem on `com.example.MyApp.UI.AddressEditor.AddressEditorActivity.void setEntryStart(java.util.Date)(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Yes, you have to look into setEntryStart(), there may be some values you are setting as null.

Comment: @ shayan pourvatan, @Pankaj: I have updated my question to post the code of `setEntryStart`. I cannot see where an `Ecxeption` should happen.

Comment: if (_entryEnd != null && _entryStart != null){
if(_entryEnd.before(_entryStart))
_entryEnd = _entryStart;
}

Comment: I understand what you mean, but all sources I found say that Java uses short-circuit evaluation for && and || in if-statements. Thus `_entryEnd.before(_entryStart)` is only evaluated if both `_entryEnd` and `_entryStart` ARE NOT null. So what difference would it make to use two if-clauses?

Comment: hmm, is setEntryStart() only contains these code snippet or doing something else? As log says that possibly you are storing some values in preferences? 
and one more thing that are you unable to reproduce this issue on local APK?

Comment: This is the original code of `setEntryStart` thus it does not anything else and I do not understand how this code should raise an `NullPointerException`.

Nothing is stored to preferences but some values are loaded from / stored in `savedInstanceState`.

Answer (score 0):

These are stack traces and method are called from stack and stack is LIFO (Last in first out)

So, you have to read it from top to bottom.

EG: if you call m1() from main() ,m2() from m1() and m3() from m2() the stack will be

main()->m1()->m2()->m3()

Comment: Thanks! Of course I know that a stack is LIFO but as described there the stack trace does not make sense when I read it top to bottom. First thing is, that there seem to be two parts which have to be read separatly. Secondly the methodes in the second part DO NOT call each other. Reading `setCategory -> setEntryStart` does not make sense since `setCategory`does not call `setEntryStart`...